# How to join lines that touch each other in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Basically I want to merge all the line segments that intersect into one line as shown below in orange

So each line segment would have their own id. In other words, one of the lines circle in orange would have id of 1, the other id of 2 and so one for every segment that isn't part of the network of connecting lines

Code I've tried so far is

```
     create table dec_board_ber_roads_merged5 as
SELECT row_number() over (order by a.interest),a.interest, 
ST_LineMerge(ST_Collect(a.geom))
FROM roads_ber as a 
LEFT JOIN roads_ber as b ON 
ST_Touches(a.geom,b.geom) 
AND a.interest = b.interest
AND a.id = b.id
GROUP BY ST_Touches(a.geom,b.geom), a.interest, a.id
```

[image]

Comment: Would You show us sample data or a fiddle?

Comment: Maybe You find these links useful: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineMerge.html

Comment: Why are you joining on AND a.id = b.id? If I understood your goal, that should be a.id != b.id

Comment: What is a.id? Is it a street ID, or a segment ID? If it is a segment ID, you should remove it from the group-by clause and follow @fradal83 comment.